# Realm-js and Node.js: exception during login to Realm Object Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, realm

I'm continue my tests of the realm-js. I wrote little test to check synchronization with server:

```
'use strict';

var Realm = require('realm');

const SmsSchema = {
    phone: 'string',
    msg: 'string',
    uuid: 'string',
    status: 'int'
};

var realm;
Realm.Sync.User.login('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9080','login','password', (error, user) => {
    if (!error) {
        realm = new Realm({
            sync: {
                user: user,
                url: 'realm://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9080/~/SMSService',
            },
            schema: [SmsSchema]
        });
    }
    else
        console.log('Connection error!');
});


realm.close();
```

After start of this test I have got the following exception:

```
Realm.Sync.User.login('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:9080','login','password', (error, user) => {
      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'User' of undefined
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/hermann/WebstormProjects/SMSService/app.js:15:11)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Can anybody help me with this error? I have to add that I never before met Node.js and and my last experience with JavaScript was more than one year ago...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the sync APIs for Linux in `realm-js` are only available with the Professional/Enterprise Edition of Realm Mobile Platform. You will have to sign up for a free trial [here](https://realm.io/pricing/realm-professional-edition/). The public free version on NPM does not include Linux support for sync.

Comment: may I ask you one more question? I installed trial version of the realm-js, but during login I have got the following error: `Error: 'name' must be of type: string`. I don't understand where is this variable 'name'?

Comment: Are you passing something other than a string as the username during the login?

Comment: no, I'm passing exactly the same like in my code above. Of course with real IP, login and password. Maybe it is because the real name is e-mail address ('smsuser@mail.ru')?

Comment: yes, it seems the reason is wrong user name, what I have to do if Realm Server accepts e-mail address as user name during registration?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce yes, `sync` is available on React Native

Comment: @AdamFish Where does it say Linux is not supported for free? https://realm.io/pricing/

Comment: The language used for this is "Server-side data access and integrations" which is under Professional Edition. Sorry for the confusion!